# How to make PHPUnit explain deprecations and warnings?

Tags: phpunit, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I'm just learning how to use PHPUnit. I'm running it from the command line, and among the results I get `OK, but there are issues! Tests: 5, Assertions: 15, Warnings: 2, Deprecations: 5.`

I can't work out how to get it to explain what caused the deprecations and warnings counts. **How do I find out what's causing it in my test code?** I've tried adding the flag `--display-deprecations` but it doesn't change anything.

I'm using flags `--testdox`, `--stderr` and `-v` but they aren't helping. And I've tried `--debug` and `--verbose` but it says neither of them are supported flags.

How do I know what the problem in my code is? While I'm at it, I might as well ask you guys. Here's my test code:

```
final class FetchForErrorsTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider urlsForBasicTest
     */
    public function testNoErrors($url)
    {
        $rr = new RequestResponse(TestConf::$rootUrl.'/'.$url);
        $body = $rr->get();
        $this->assertStringEndsWith('</html>', rtrim($body));
        $this->assertEquals($rr->status, 200);
    }
    public static function urlsForBasicTest()
    {
        return [
            ['index.php'],
            ...
        ];
    }
}
```

I'm also getting deprecation and warning alerts for the following, without any further explanations:

```
final class DIContainerTest extends TestCase
{
    public static $di;
    public static $foo;
    public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
    {
        self::$di = new DIContainer();
        self::$di->register(
            ["Bar", "BarInterface"], 
            "Bar", 'singleton'
        );
        self::$di->register(
            ["Foo", "FooInterface"],
            "Foo"
        );
    }
    public function testCalledFactory()
    {
        self::$foo = self::$di->call("FooInterface::make");
        $this->assertEquals(get_class(self::$foo), "Foo");
    }
    public function testRecursivelyInstantatedConcretes()
    {
        self::$foo = self::$di->call("FooInterface::make");
        $this->assertEquals(get_class(self::$foo->bar), "Bar");
    }
}
```

It would be really good to find a way to make it more explicit about what the deprecations and warnings are.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You need to configure the phpunit.xml file to customize how it treats warnings, deprecations etc. This normally goes in the root of your project.

It will look something like this and there are a number of ways you can configure it I just picked some options here check the docs at https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.1/configuration.html for all the options.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerDeprecations="true"
         displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerErrors="true"
         displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerNotices="true"
         displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerWarnings="true"
         strict="true"
         >
</phpunit>
```

Comment: This didn’t work for me as those didn’t seem to be valid options in the most recent version ( at least for the convert….

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.1/configuration.html#the-displaydetailsonteststhattriggererrors-attribute

add these values ( specifically testdox="false" ) then it seemed to display the actual message instead of D

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    testdox="false" 
    displayDetailsOnIncompleteTests="true"
    displayDetailsOnSkippedTests="true"
    displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerDeprecations="true"
    displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerErrors="true"
    displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerNotices="true"
    displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerWarnings="true"
>
```

but the output is not as pretty as before.. but at least i can see them now..

Comment: I confirm that `displayDetailsOnTestsThatTriggerDeprecations="true"` must be explicitely set AND the `testdox` option must be disabled. With `testdox` enabled, the explanations for the deprecation warnings are not displayed. PHPUnit bug or feature ?